# How can I keep a bat file repeating constantly?

Tags: batch-file, process, cmd, command, repeat

sorry if I am using wrong terms, I am new to this stuff. so I have been trying to get this command (taskkill /f /t /im (the process)) to keep repeating because the process that I am trying to kill keeps coming back. so I thought if i can get the command to keep repeating it will keep the process closed. please I would like some help, thank you.

Comment: You can use `goto` to jump back to the beginning, but isn't it better to attack this problem at the root? WHY does the process keep coming back?

Comment: Thx every one for your help I will try to use your ways to find a solution to my probelm. Again thx.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through

```
@echo off

:loop
taskkill /f /t /im (the process)
goto loop
```

Or add a delay using `ping` or `timeout`

```
@echo off

:loop
taskkill /f /t /im (the process)
timeout /t 30 /nobreak >nul rem Change out 30 for the number of seconds needed in the delay
goto loop
```

As @MrLister said in the comments above, address the problem directly. Ask yourself "did i get this program from a reliable source?" if not, it could be malicious. If it is safe, then why is this behavior occurring? Could it be scheduled with taskscheduler? Best of luck.